# Visual Studio Code, container: terminal hangs very long before prompt appears

Tags: visual-studio-code, containers, development-environment

I'm using Visual Studio Code to develop within a Docker container (notably, `mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/javascript-node:0-12`).
This is the content of my  `settings.json` file:

```
{
    "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.linux": "zsh",
    "terminal.integrated.profiles.linux": {
        
        "bash": {
            "path": "/usr/bin/flatpak-spawn",
            "args": [
                "--host",
                "--env=TERM=xterm-256color",
                "bash"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

When I issue any command in the terminal, it executes correctly, but it takes very long for the prompt to appear again.

What is causing this behaviour? How can the problem be solved?

Answer (score 1):

With recent vscode devcontainers, I found that I needed to do something like this instead, as **bash** appears to be the default shell, instead of **zsh**.

```
"postCreateCommand": "git config --global codespaces-theme.hide-info 1 && git config --global codespaces-theme.hide-status 1 && git config --global codespaces-theme.hide-dirty 1"
```

See: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-dev-containers/issues/1196

There might be additional changes coming as well, based on https://github.com/devcontainers/features/pull/326

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that the delay was due to a combination of:

- poor container's file system behaviour because bind-mount'ed to the local machine's one (Linux container on Windows machine)
- project consisting of a large number of (small, actually) source files (~10,000)
- git information displayed on the prompt

To solve the issue, I ended up disabling git's processing every time (as described at https://giters.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/issues/9848 ), by adding a **postCreateCommand** in *devcontainer.json* file.

This is the content of my *devcontainer.json*:

```
"postCreateCommand": "git config --global oh-my-zsh.hide-info 1 && git config --global oh-my-zsh.hide-status 1 && git config --global oh-my-zsh.hide-dirty 1"
```